# Converting byte json-like array to a python dict. All solutions did not work

Tags: python, json, dictionary, apache-kafka, byte

```
b'{"BusinessEntityID": 23, "Title": null, "FirstName": "Mary", "MiddleName": "E", "LastName": "Gibson", "Suffix": null, "JobTitle": "Marketing Specialist", "PhoneNumber": "531-555-0183", "PhoneNumberType": "Work", "EmailAddress": "mary0@adventure-works.com", "EmailPromotion": 0, "AddressLine1": "3928 San Francisco", "AddressLine2": null, "City": "Everett", "StateProvinceName": "Washington", "PostalCode": "98201", "CountryRegionName": "United States", "AdditionalContactInfo": null}'
```

I'm consuming the above with Kafka and I want to extract it to a python dict.
I've tried decoding and doing json.loads but this error is triggered `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

also this did not work. Here is my code:

```
try: 
    while True:
        msg = consumer.poll(1.0)
        if msg is None:
            print('...')
        elif msg.error() is None:
            msg_string = ''.join(map(chr, msg.value()))
            print(type(msg_string)) # <class 'str'>
            record = json.loads(msg_string) # ERROR: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0
            print(record)
        elif msg.error() is not None:
            print(f'Msg Error {msg.error()}')
except Exception as e:
    print(f'ERROR: {e}')
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried json.decode()

Comment: What are you trying to do there: `msg_string = ''.join(map(chr, msg.value()))`

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert it into normal string using `a.decode('utf-8')` and then use `json.loads` to convert it into `JSON` object

```
a = b'{"BusinessEntityID": 23, "Title": null, "FirstName": "Mary", "MiddleName": "E", "LastName": "Gibson", "Suffix": null, "JobTitle": "Marketing Specialist", "PhoneNumber": "531-555-0183", "PhoneNumberType": "Work", "EmailAddress": "mary0@adventure-works.com", "EmailPromotion": 0, "AddressLine1": "3928 San Francisco", "AddressLine2": null, "City": "Everett", "StateProvinceName": "Washington", "PostalCode": "98201", "CountryRegionName": "United States", "AdditionalContactInfo": null}'

j = json.loads(a.decode('utf-8'))
print(j)
```

Thank you

Comment: `json.loads()` support bytes [*(since 3.6)*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Comment: It is working fine for me. 
Can you print the msg_string and provide the output of it, so we can see where the mistake is

Comment: It turns out that there is some old data in Kafka topic that could not be converted. Created new topic and all is good now. Thanks